# Combine showing multiple figure labels

Tags: floats, labels

I have two sub-figures in a figure (say `Figure M`) called `a` and `b`. How can I combine showing multiple figure labels like this?

> Figure Ma and b

P.S. I can easily get the following figure labels by command `Figure \ref{fig_M_a} and \ref{fig_M_b}` (assume the labels for them are `fig_M_a` and `fig_M_b` respectively):

> Figure Ma and Mb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\subref`; in the following example I assumed [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) was used to produce the subfigures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

As we can see in Figures~\ref{fig:testa} and~\subref{fig:testb}...

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{first subfigure\label{fig:testa}}{\rule{4cm}{1cm}}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{second subfigure\label{fig:testb}}{\rule{4cm}{1cm}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using  [`subfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) and `\subfloat` this will produce the desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{subrefformat=simple,labelformat=parens,listofformat=subsimple}

\begin{document}

As we can see in Figures~\ref{fig:testa} and~\subref{fig:testb}...

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[first subfigure\label{fig:testa}]{\rule{4cm}{1cm}}\qquad
\subfloat[second subfigure\label{fig:testb}]{\rule{4cm}{1cm}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I will get `Figure Ma and (b)`. Any idea? P.S. I am using `\subfloat`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao please see my updated answer.

Comment: It works now. Thanks. It didn't work previously because the `\label{...}` is outside the `\subfloat[...]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put a `\caption{}` and corresponding `\label{}` for the whole figure, and reference that. That sounds like what you really want.

Comment: Yes, I have one for the whole figure. But here I want to refer to some parts of the figures. Thanks anyway.